# Sort pandas column of lists and call other columns

Tags: python, pandas

**I have seen several posts on this, but every solution i attempt i either get an error or the post is slightly different than what i need. See attempts below.**

**dataframe**:

```
col1
[0.7, 0.8, -0.9]
[0.3, 0.7, 0.1]
```

**I'm hoping to sort the elements in each list in this column in ascending order like this:**

```
results
[-0.9, 0.7, 0.8]
[0.1, 0.3, 0.7]
```

**Attempts**:

```
#attempt1
#sorts the column based on the first element in the list
#also tried grabbing other columns with [['col1','col2']] at the end but that doesn't work
sorted(df['jaro_sequencer_diff'])

#attempt2
df['col1'].head().sorted(reverse=True)

#AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'sorted'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted`:

```
df['col1'].apply(sorted)
#or
df['col1'] = [sorted(l) for l in df['col1']]
```

Comment: nvm - my mistake. this works fine. I need to stop working today!